# Adjust Cylinder transform to match 2 given points

Tags: unity-game-engine, geometry, transform

Suppose I have a cylinder (of height 2, length and width 1) that contains two children **top** and **bottom** and 2 given points in space **p1** and **p2**, just like this:

[image]

How can I evaluate the rotation of this cylinder so that **top** go to **p1**, **bottom** go to **p2** and the cylinder align correctly with the points? This is the result I want:

[image]

---

The final position of the cylinder should be (p1 + p2)/2 and the y-scale should be (p1 - p2).magnitude / 2, since the cylinder has natural height of 2.

Comment: What happened to your last question where people already gave their recommendations?

Comment: The question didn't reflect well what I needed and `Transform.LookAt` focuses on z-axis, not on y.

Comment: I totally understood what the goal is and it doesn't really matter whether it is a cube or cylinder. Also the comment on `LookAt` stays the same: you can use it. Simply rotate the cylinder correctly (namely so its local Y axis matches with the parent's Z axis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a previous question you said your cylinder has a parent object so as mentioned you could either use [`Transform.LookAt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html)

> Rotates the transform so the **forward vector** points at /target/'s current position.

or also [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html)

> Creates a rotation with the specified forward and upwards directions.

on your parent object and just make sure the cylinder is rotated in a way so its local Y-axis matches with the parent object 's Z-axis => local rotation is `-90°, 0, 0`

Or you could simply add this rotation to the result of `Quaternion.LookRotation` like e.g.

```c#
private Quaternion offset = Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0);

public void ApplyPoints(Transform cylinder, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2)
{
    var delta = p2 - p1;

    // First apply the world space rotation so the forward vector points p1 to p2
    cylinder.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(delta);
    // Then add the local offset around the local X axis
    cylinder.localRotation *= offset;
    // Or also
    //cylinder.Rotate(-90, 0, 0);

    // Set the position to the center between p1 and p2
    cylinder.position = (p1 + p2) / 2f;

    // Set the Y scale to the half of the distance between p1 and p2    
    var scale = cylinder.localScale;
    scale.y = delta.magnitude / 2f;
    cylinder.localScale = scale;
}
```

---

Alternatively to that you could also simply assign desired direction to [`Transform.up`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-up.html)

```c#
public void ApplyPoints(Transform cylinder, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2)
{
    var delta = p2 - p1;

    // YES! It is possible to simply set the up, right or forward direction 
    // so the object is rotated accordingly
    cylinder.up = delta;

    // Set the position to the center between p1 and p2
    cylinder.position = (p1 + p2) / 2f;

    // Set the Y scale to the half of the distance between p1 and p2    
    var scale = cylinder.localScale;
    scale.y = delta.magnitude / 2f;
    cylinder.localScale = scale;
}
```