# Point Cloud Registration With Known Correspondence in Unity with C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry, transform, point-clouds

So I have a known set of points on a scanned 3D model of a physical object (let's say cube) named p1(x,y,z), p2(x,y,z) and p3(x,y,z).

The previously mention physical object is in front of the user and the user is going to tap the same 3 point on the physical cube (in quest 3 passthrough) that correspond to p1, p2, p3 that are p1', p2' and p3'. Though, p1', p2' and p3' may not be a perfect square as the user is only a human. How can I move the scanned 3D model to the location of the physical model that the user inputed?

[Here's an image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB6su.png)

Of course I looked at point cloud registration techniques like [Umeyama's method](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs273/refs/umeyama.pdf) but this seem very complex to implement in C# for my personally, though there is a python implementation[here](https://gist.github.com/nh2/bc4e2981b0e213fefd4aaa33edfb3893#file-rigid-transform-with-scale-py-L20-L39). With this solution, I wouldn't actually know how to perform the translation with the resulting matrix... Looking for a slightly easier solution I found another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68350906/adjust-cylinder-transform-to-match-2-given-points)  that does it with 2 points. This got me thinking that maybe I can use the same algorithm for two points, p1 and p2, to match it with p1' and p2' then rotate the model iteratively about p1' -> p2' until the p3 and p3' are at the somewhat exact position.

Comment: Umeyama's algorithm (or in your case, [Kabsch's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm) since you don't need scaling) is the way to go. Once you have the matrix, you just apply it to your input points and you are done. It does not get much simpler than that. You just need to find a suitable linear algebra library that calculates the singular value decomposition of the covariance matrix. As far as I am aware, Unity does not have a built-in function for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Kabsch solver for Unity in [Jonathan Selstad's MathUtilities](https://github.com/zalo/MathUtilities/). He also wrote a [blog post about it](https://zalo.github.io/blog/kabsch/).

Note that the sample continuously calls the solver in `Update`. If you only solve once, you can edit the `extractRotation` method to use more iterations.